# Is there a way to instruct a C++ compiler to skip rest of current file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

Once in a while some functionality has to be conditionally compiled. For example, there's `class Logger` that is only used when `WITH_LOGGING` macro is `#define`d:

```
// Logger.cpp
#ifdef WITH_LOGGING
#include <Logger.h>
// several hundred lines
// of class Logger
// implementation
// follows
#endif
```

which is not very convenient - unless the reader scrolls through the file he can't be sure that the matching `#endif` is position at the end of file and so the whole file contents is excluded with the `#ifdef`. I'd prefre to have something like this:

```
// Logger.cpp
#ifndef WITH_LOGGING
#GetOutOfThisFile
#endif
#include <Logger.h>
// several hundred lines
// of class Logger
// implementation
// follows
```

so that it's clear that once the `WITH_LOGGING` is not `#define`d the compiler just skips the rest of the file.

Is something like that possible in C++?

Comment: Couldn't you just comment it in? `//If this is not defined nothing in here gets compiled` seems to be to the point i think.

Comment: This is essentially what include guards do, and nobody seems to be bothered by having an `#ifdef` at the beginning of the file and an `#endif` at the end of the file for almost every header file.

Comment: This is (one of the reasons) why text editors have block collapsing.

Comment: I would argue that it's a lot more confusing if you glance at code and don't immediately realize that it's not being included despite not having an #endif at the end.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point but shouldn't this be done by the build system (`make` or whatever) ? I mean, if the source file is empty (after preprocessing) why even compile it ?

Comment: @ereOn: I don't really care about compilation efficiency, I mostly care of readability.

Comment: @In silico: If nobody was bothered by include guards, nobody would have implemented `#pragma once`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I didn't say that nobody was bothered by include guards per se, I said that nobody was bothered by having an `#ifdef` at the beginning of the file and an `#endif` at the end of the file as required for include guards. As far as I know `#pragma once` was invented so that you don't have to come up with a unique macro name for every single header file, not because of the `#ifdef`/`#endif` thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to clarify this would be to put the implementation in another file which is included:

file Logger.cpp:

```
#ifdef WITH_LOGGING
 #include <Logger.h>
 #include "logger.impl"
#endif
```

file logger.impl:

```
// several hundred lines
// of class Logger
// implementation
// follows
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `#` part of the directive has to be in the first column of the document.

Comment: @in silco:  The `#` has to be the first non-whitespace character on a line.  Indenting *greatly* increases readability, in preprocessing controls as well as nested data and code.

Comment: +1 That would do it, I've actually seen lots of places where this is done.

Comment: @wallyk: I stand corrected. But at no point did I ever say that there should be no indentation. I've seen people do something like `#ifdef`/`# include` (note the space between `#` and `include`), so I thought that requiring `#` at the first column was the case.

Comment: @wallyk, In silico: In the traditional preprocessing, there must be no leading whitespace - the `#` has to be in the first column (but whitespace is allowed after the `#`). See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-miscellany.html#Traditional-miscellany ; in the ISO preprocessor language (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/The-preprocessing-language.html#The-preprocessing-language ), leading whitespace is allowed as is trailing whitespace. Hence, the safest bet is to use trailing whitespace only, e.g. `#  include "logger.impl"`

Comment: @Frerich Raabe "Traditional" preprocessing became out of date with the first C standard (1989).  Earlier forms obviously endured for a little bit after that, but that was over 20 years ago.  I can't imagine traditional preprocessing being relevant today.

Comment: @Frerich:  I'm not sure what "traditional" that might be.  I successfully indented `#` on Unix V6 in 1978.  The main quirk about that preprocessor was that it ran only if the first character of the file was `#`, a requirement I still fulfill today.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to exclude the contents of that file? If I understand correctly, the code in it would not be used if the define was not set. In that case, link-time optimization should remove those functions from the executable regardless.

This won't work if you have functions overridden from other libraries, but for the regular case (and most likely for logging) this will be enough. In GCC this is --ffunction-sections for the compiler and --gc-sections for the linker. Visual Studio should have comparable flags but I don't know what they are.